# Read multiple files using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a list with a few filenames

```
ListOfFiles = ['filename1.xlsm', 'filename2.xlsm',...]
```

What I want to do, is to load these files in an automated way.
So I wrote the following:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
for i in LisOfFiles:
    xl = load_workbook(ListOfFiles[i], read_only=True)
```

However I get a `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already iterating over the list. No need to index it again:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

for path in ListOfFiles:
    xl = load_workbook(path, read_only=True)
```

**Edit**

Note that in the code above, `xl` gets re-assigned every time. This is probably not what you want.

You could capture the workbooks in a list:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbooks = []
for path in ListOfFiles:
    workbooks.append(load_workbook(path, read_only=True))
```

This can be shortened by using a *list comprehension*:

```
workbooks = [
    load_workbook(path, read_only=True)
    for path in ListOfFiles
]
```

If you want to be able to address them by filename, use a *dict comprehension*:

```
workbooks = {
    path: load_workbook(path, read_only=True)
    for path in ListOfFiles
}
```

Comment: So imagine that I want to perform some operation in each file independently without overwriting the previous file.
For example, the operation could be  `df = pd.Dataframe(some_column)`
How could I do this without overwiriting the previous files?

Comment: @eduardo2111 Save the data in a `list` or `dict`. See updated answer. I've added some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing i in the for loop `print(i)`. Basically you are trying to access an element of a list with a string. In the first iteration this means 
`i = 'filename1.xlsm'` which translates to
`LisOfFiles['filename1.xlsm']`

However you can only access the elements of a list with a number i.e. `LisOfFiles[0]` works fine.

The solution is to directly use i as input to load_workbook. However be aware that in every iteration of the loop xl gets overwritten

```
for i in LisOfFiles: 
    xl = load_workbook(i, read_only= True)
```